# Thread For Each Game Room In Java Server?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, server, multiplayer

I am developing a multiplayer game which has a lobby where people can join different games.

I am curious about if I should start a thread for each game room.

I am using java.io so I already have a thread for each player.

Even though there is not heavy load on each thread will having many threads slow down my server?

If I host a server for 100 players and 30 rooms can an avarage virtual server handle 150 threads at once? Or it would impact the gameplay?

It is a real time game where I need instant message delivery for each position update (UDP)?

Comment: Generally, having more threads than things you can usefully do at the same time hurts performance. But with numbers this small, the small difference in performance probably isn't worth the additional complexity. (The performance cost from the fact that you can't do a little bit of work for each of the 100 clients and the 30 rooms without switching threads 130 times or so. With a more efficient design, all those context switches can be avoided.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes having separate objects for each player  and connection makes the design a lot easier. Thanks for the advice it's good to focus to my design rather than worrying too much about other things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread (as you already know) simply allows tasks to be run at the same time. Having loads of threads will not always help or disadvantage the servers speed, this is limited by other factors like you internet speed or the processing power of the computer. The gameplay of the people on the other side will run as fast as the computer can handle all the requests, even if you have 10000 threads they will all require processing power and connections through the internet.

**In short, the speed of the server and the client/s will be affected by other people using your server, the speed will be limited by the speed of your internet connections and/or your CPU power.**

If this hasn't answered your question please define the actual question more clearly rather than asking lots of general questions.

EDIT:
After reading your comment my advice: do whatever you think will be best for the server. Having a load of strands will not affect your server for the good or bad. :)

Comment: Thanks that comforted me enough. I just wanted to know if it is not going to be really bad even though it's not the best option for a server.